# Drawable image not showing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I am having a problem in recyclerView, that it is not showing an image from drawable resource.

I have stored the imageResource in a data class with other text and audioResource and then populated the recyclerView using adapter. Everything is working, like the text is shown correctly, the audio is being played, only the image view is not showing the image, instead it is showing a purple box.

Here is the data class

```
    @Parcelize
    data class Word (
       // English Translation of word
       var englishTranslation: String,
       // French Translation of word
       var frenchTranslation: String,
       // Image resource for corresponding image to the word
       var imageResourceId: Int,
       // Audio resource for the pronunciation of the word
       var audioResourceId: Int,
       // String for description of image
       var imageContentDescription: String,
       // String for description of audio
       var audioResourceContentDescription: String): Parcelable
```

and this is the actual list Data

```
    private val fruits: MutableList<Word> = mutableListOf(
        Word("Apple", "Pomme",
            R.drawable.ic_image_apple, R.raw.des_fruits, "Image of the apple",
            "pronunciation of the audio"),
        Word("Orange", "Orange",
            R.drawable.ic_image_apple, R.raw.des_fruits, "image of the Orange",
            "Plays the pronunciation audio"),
        Word("Strawberry", "Fraise",
            R.drawable.ic_image_apple, R.raw.des_fruits, "image of the Strawberry",
            "Plays the pronunciation audio")
    )
```

and below here is the xml code of imageView in recyclerView item layout

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/word_image"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@{word.imageContentDescription}"
        android:src="@{word.imageResourceId}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_image_apple" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved now, I used the Kotlin's Binding adapter and that solved the problem